# Grab id of select from option element

Tags: jquery

How do I get the Id of the parent `select` from the `option` element.
I have tried:

```
if (formInput.value === "NC") {
     //console.log($('option[value="NC"]').closest('select').attr('id'));
            var a = $('option[value="NC"]').parent().attr('id');
            console.log(a);
    }
```

From where `formInput === "NC"` I want to get the id `capability_32`

```
<select class="form-control" id="capability_32" name="capability_32" onchange="showDropDown('nc32', this.value)">
        <option value="0">-- Outcome --</option>
        <option value="C">Compliant</option>
        <option value="OBS">Observation</option>
        <option value="NC">Non-Compliant</option>
        <option value="NA">Not Applicable</option>
</select>
```

JS Function

```
var showDropDown = function showDropDown(div, value) {
'use strict';
 var nc = document.getElementById(div);
  if (value === "NC" || value === "OBS") {
    nc.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
     nc.style.display = 'none';
  }
}


    function fetchOrderFromLocalStorage() {
    localKey = $('#ddl').children(':selected').text();

    var mcs = localStorage.getItem(localKey);
    var jsn = JSON.parse(mcs);

    if (mcs.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < jsn.length; i++) {
        var formInput = jsn[i],
            $el = $("[name='" + formInput.name + "']"),
            type = $el.attr('type');

        switch (type) {
            case 'checkbox':
                $el.attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            case 'radio':
                $el.filter('[value="' + formInput.value + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                $el.val(formInput.value);
            default:
                $el.val(formInput.value);
        }
        if (formInput.value === "NC") {
            //console.log($('option[value="NC"]').closest('select').attr('id'));
            var a = $('select').filter(':selected');
            console.log(a);
            $(a).css("display", "block");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `showDropDown` function.

Comment: (you shouldn't mix JS with HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it works: proved below (i put the code in the onchange function)

```
var showDropDown = function showDropDown(div, value) {
    'use strict';
    console.log(value);
    var nc = document.getElementById(div);
    if (value === "NC") {
        //console.log($('option[value="NC"]').closest('select').attr('id'));
        var a = $('option[value="NC"]').parent().attr('id');
        console.log(a);
    }
    if (value === "NC" || value === "OBS") {
        //nc.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        //nc.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/18xdq19g/1/

leads me to believe your formInput variable is wrong, or the placement of the code? how do you define formInput?

Comment: ok I have looked through and as i can't see local storage and the ddl contents (don't add it) i can't work out what (if anything) goes wrong when you get into the for loop. can you add some console.logs? see if where something like formInput.name is what you expect? I'd expect the problem to be around there though

Comment: nothing goes wrong, I want to get the id of the select where the `formInput.value === "NC"` and then unhide a textarea with css, there could be 1 or 30 `selects`